# How to rename an app name?

Tags: android

[image]

This is my project which is a small game for Android. I thought when I upload it to play store the name under the game icon will be chosen there in the upload form. But it's not and I don't even know where is the name that is displayed under the icon taken from, because the project name is "MyApplication" yet the name under the icon is "simplecount" so how to change it ?

Also there are some ads in my app, there is an option to use device location in play store to determine which ads to display, currently my app does not ask for location access but will it be beneficial if I ask for it for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your application is defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, using the `android:label` attribute in the `application`tag:

```xml
<application
    android:label="your app name">
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to do this is to copy the project and then change the root folder name on the copy.
Then just open copy as a new project in Android Studio.

Comment: ... and this is **the easiest way**??